# Change properties of rel attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to change values defined in rel attribute with jQuery
For example on this code

```
<a href='http://www.professorcloud.com/images/zoomengine/bigimage01.jpg' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Thumbnail 2' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: 'http://www.professorcloud.com/images/zoomengine/smallimage-1.jpg'">
<img src="http://www.professorcloud.com/images/zoomengine/tinyimage-1.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 2"/></a>
```

I want to change the values of "useZoom" and "smallImage" in this case. I found out how to get this values out of the code but I want to change/modify them.

Is it possible?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: `$("a").attr("rel", new_value)`

Comment: I have a feeling what he's really looking for is something that will parse the `key: value, key: value` structure of the `rel` attribute, so he can replace individual parts.

Comment: Precisely @Barmar, I need to change individual values of the keys.